# Form Authentication ask for relogin

Tags: c#, .net

I am using

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, true);
```

and I set 'true' to persist cookie. But when user do login it redirected user to desired page.

if user without getting log out close the browser, and reopen the browser access the URL it again show a login page.

Any Idea what I am missing in my implementation?

Thanx

Comment: Check your Auth cookie on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a permanent cookie not a session cookie with persist = true.

Comment: So how can I achieve what I an trying to do?

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, false);`